# How to trigger a SOLR full import via HTTP with clean, commit for a specific entity

Tags: solr, dataimporthandler, data-import, reindex

I'm trying to perform a Solr full import with clean, commit for a specific entity via HTTP.

I assume there should be a mechanism to automate the manual full import required in cases of manual deletion.

I have tried the HTTP call for full commit below, however I couldn't find anything specific to trigger re-indexing:

```
[solr url]/update?commit=true
```

As a note, I have 2 Solr cores defined and looking to perform this for one of them.

Thanks in advance.